# The CSS doesn't apply to jsx

Tags: css, reactjs

This is the css file  named Layout.css :

```
.Content {

      margin-top: 16px;
      color : red;

}
```

and this is the component named Layout.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './Layout.css';
// const Fragment = React.Fragment;
const { Fragment } = React;

const Layout = (props) => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div> toolbar , sidedrawer , backdrop </div>

      <main className={classes.Content}>{props.children}</main>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

and the problem is the css doesnt apply to component, i have this problem in my several components.

Comment: are you using create-react-app?

Comment: @supra28 yes,i do

Comment: You are using importing and using it improperly, i've added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import your css file like this :

```
import './Layout.css';
```

and then use the class like this :

```
<main className="Content">{props.children}</main>
```

Comment: your solution is correct, but I see this "import classes from" method in some places and that was working. any idea why it doesn't work in my code?

Comment: That works when you are actually exporting something from your file like a class or a function, You would mostly see that in css-in-js solutions where css is written in a js file and then exported, here you are not exporting anything.

Comment: it is from some tutorial and that CSS import method is working

Comment: I think they are using css-modules, you might want check this out https://medium.com/nulogy/how-to-use-css-modules-with-create-react-app-9e44bec2b5c2